# Sorting array in dictionary in python by specific key value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dictionary:

```
products = { 
'count': 3, 
'items': [ {'order': 2, 'name': green}, 
           {'order': 1, 'name': red}, 
           {'order': 3, 'name': blue} ] 
}
```

how can I sort the dictionary by the value of 'order' from highest to lowest so it results like this:

```
products = { 
'count': 3, 
'items': [ {'order': 3, 'name': blue}, 
           {'order': 2, 'name': green}, 
           {'order': 1, 'name': red} ] 
}
```

Comment: See the `key` parameter of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items contains a list of orders, so you can apply .sort() with a lambda function on your list:

```
products["items"].sort(key=lambda x: x["order"], reverse=True)
```

Reverse is True because you want a descending order.